# Rails: Accessing data of other SQL table in View

Tags: sql, database, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller

I don't understand how access data from my View in other table.

I have few models. First is *User*, second is *UsersPreferences*. So i have settings page for users and code looks like this:

```
<%= render 'shared/error_messages', :object => f.object %>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label        :name %><br />
  <%= f.text_field   :name %>
</div>
...
<div class="checkbox">
  <%= f.check_box :notification_about_new_followers %>                        
  <%= f.label     'Notify via email about new followers' %><br />
</div>
```

This code works (*User* has row **notification_about_new_followers**) but i want to change it. I decided that better way is keep preferences in other table. So i created model *UsersPreferences* which has **user_id** and flag '**notify_about_new_followers**'. I tried to rewrite my view like that:

```
<%= render 'shared/error_messages', :object => f.object %>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label        :name %><br />
  <%= f.text_field   :name %>
</div>
...
<div class="checkbox">
  <%= f.check_box UsersPreferences.find_by_user_id(@user.id).notify_about_new_followers %>                        
  <%= f.label     'Notify via email about new followers' %><br />
</div>
```

But when i visit page with code i get such error

```
undefined method `true' for #<User:0x007f8ac180dee8>
```

How can i solve this error?

*User* model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, ... , :notification_about_new_followers
  ...
  has_one  :users_preferences
end
```

*UsersPreferences* model:

```
class UsersPreferences < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, :class_name => "User"
  attr_accessible :notify_about_new_followers
end
```

Comment: Please, [get really familiar with MVC](http://jordanhall.co.uk/programming/simple-explanation-of-model-view-controller-mvc-2206990/) before you get into some bad habits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
<%= f.check_box UsersPreferences.find_by_user_id(@user.id).notify_about_new_followers %>
```

is causing the error. `UsersPreferences.find_by_user_id(@user.id).notify_about_new_followers` is `true`, so essentially that line reads:

```
<%= f.check_box true %>
```

And like the error says, there is no 'true' attribute for your UserPreferences model.

To fix this you'll need to first read up on MVC (Model-View-Controller). Without knowing how MVC works, you'll never be able to move forward with Rails. There are a lot of great resources out there, just [google "Model View Controller for rails"](http://www.google.com/search?gcx=w&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=MVC#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&source=hp&q=Model+View+Controller+for+rails&pbx=1&oq=Model+View+Controller+for+rails&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=6783l6999l1l7159l4l2l0l0l0l1l240l240l2-1l1l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=de4ce0a5d4a08049&biw=1094&bih=930). [Here is a good one](http://slash7.com/2005/02/22/mvc-the-most-vexing-conundrum/). A little goofy, though... if that's not your style, try another link.

After you have learned that, look up the rails helper `fields_for`, and there you will find your answer.